# How do you define a an array of objects within an array in typescript

Tags: typescript

So if you want to define a array of objects you would do this:

```
public racks: Rack[];
```

However, I want to able to make an array that takes in more arrays of racks so for example,

```
[ 
  [rack1, rack2, rack3], 
  [rack4, rack5, rack6], 
  [rack7] 
]
```

My question is how do I define it so it can accept this kind of variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an array of arrays of `Rack` :

```
public racks: Rack[][];
```

Answer (score 2):

you're looking for:

```
public racks: Array<Array<Rack>>;
```

or less verbose:

```
public racks: Rack[][];
```